# Does the Church of Jesus Christ of Latter Day Saints believe that God(s) is/are omnipresent?

Tags: nature-of-god, lds, omniprescence

Omnipresence is generally defined within Western Christianity as:

> the property of being present anywhere and everywhere. The term omnipresence is most often used in a religious context as an attribute of a deity or supreme being, while the term ubiquity is generally used to describe something "existing or being everywhere at the same time, constantly encountered, widespread, common". Ubiquitous can also be used as a synonym for words like worldwide, universal, global, pervasive, all over the place.
> The omnipresence of a supreme being is conceived differently by different religious systems. In monotheistic beliefs like Christianity, and Judaism the divine and the universe are separate, but the divine is present everywhere. - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence

God remains transcendent to His creation and yet is immanent in relating to it.  He can act within creation anytime and everywhere, whatever he wants: He cannot be excluded from any location or object in creation.  God is omnipresent in a way that he is able to interact with his creation however he chooses, and is the very essence of his creation.  In other words, without God's omnipresence there would be no creation as it currently stands.

God then, being omnipresent, is ontologically different (outside of or other than) the universe but is present any and everywhere within the universe.  This is to be distinguished from pantheism where God and the universe are indistinct.  Terms that we use to describe space/time are limited in their ability to fully encapsulate what is meant by the omnipresence of God.

> omnipresence doesn't mean divine occupation of all space, nor divine distribution over all space, nor indwelling of every entity, nor that God cannot move in space, nor the divinification of the universe; but means that God is fully present every-where, and that God can do different things at different places at the same time. -  Domenic Marbaniang, "Omnipresence", Light of Life, Mumbai, February 2018

David, in Psalm 139, expresses what each Western Christian everywhere can say at all times:

> Where can I go from Your Spirit?
> Or where can I flee from Your presence?
> If I ascend into heaven, You are there;
> If I make my bed in hell, behold, You are there.
> If I take the wings of the morning,
> And dwell in the uttermost parts of the sea,
> Even there Your hand shall lead me,
> And Your right hand shall hold me.
> If I say, “Surely the darkness shall fall on me,”
> Even the night shall be light about me;
> Indeed, the darkness shall not hide from You,
> But the night shines as the day;
> The darkness and the light are both alike to You.

Part of the Western Christian concept of God's omnipresence is (to quote the Highlander) "There can be only One":  The God who "[fills all in all](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ephesians%201%3A20-23&version=KJV)" does not leave room for another to also fill all in all.  LDS, on the other hand, posits an unknowable number of Gods who already are and who are yet to be.

Does the LDS Church have a similar concept of the omnipresence of God?  What, if any, are the differences?

Comment: 'Fulness' is an attribute of Deity (e.g. John 1:16). And neither the earth nor the heaven of heavens can contain this fullness (2 Chron 2:6). So if that attribute be shared, then there must be a perfection of unity in the sharers thereof. Which results in One Divine nature shared by Persons. I am supposing that this is what 'Western Christianity' accepts. But I may be wrong. Up-voted +1.

Answer (score 5):

The term "Omnipresent" is not found in the canonical scriptures of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.

---

The following statements have been made by other sources:

The Church's [Gospel Principles](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/manual/gospel-principles/chapter-7-the-holy-ghost?lang=eng) manual states (emphasis mine):

> The Holy Ghost is a member of the Godhead. He is a personage of
> Spirit. He can be in only one place at a time, but **His influence can
> be everywhere** at the same time.

From Joseph F. Smith (6th president of the Church, nephew of Joseph Smith):

> The Holy Ghost as a personage of Spirit can no more be omnipresent in
> person than can the Father or the Son, but by his intelligence, his
> knowledge, his power and influence, over and through the laws of
> nature, he is and can be omnipresent throughout all the works of God
> (*Gospel Doctrine* p. 61).

The Church's [Guide to the Study of the Scriptures](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/gs/omnipresent?lang=eng) describes Omnipresent as:

> God’s ability to be present everywhere through His spirit

---

**Related Teachings**

*The Godhead*

> The Father has a body of flesh and bones as tangible as man’s; the Son
> also; but the Holy Ghost has not a body of flesh and bones, but is a
> personage of Spirit. Were it not so, the Holy Ghost could not dwell in
> us (Doctrine & Covenants 130:22)

*The Light of Christ*

The light of Christ is [distinct](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1989/06/i-have-a-question/what-is-the-difference-between-the-holy-ghost-the-spirit-of-christ-and-the-light-of-christ?lang=eng) from the Holy Ghost. The Holy Ghost is a Personage; light is not. The light of Christ was described by apostle Marion G. Romney
as:

> the light which enlighteneth every man that cometh into the world ([source](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/ensign/1989/06/i-have-a-question/what-is-the-difference-between-the-holy-ghost-the-spirit-of-christ-and-the-light-of-christ?lang=eng))

The following are excerpts from Doctrine & Covenants 88, speaking of Christ:

> 6 He that ascended up on high, as also he descended below all things,
> in that he comprehended all things, that he might be in all and
> through all things, the light of truth;
>
> 7 Which truth shineth. This is the light of Christ...
>
> 12 Which light proceedeth forth from the presence of God to fill the
> immensity of space—
>
> 13 The light which is in all things, which giveth life to all
> things...

--

**Conclusion**

If we adopt [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnipresence) more broad definition of Omnipresence:

> Omnipresence means minimally that there is no place to which God’s
> knowledge and power do not extend

I do not see any conflict with the teachings of The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints. But if Omnipresent means one is physically present everywhere at once, The Church of Jesus Christ does not hold this view.

God is not physically everywhere at once, but His influence is.

---

Disclaimer: these thoughts are the product of my own study and do not constitute official statements by The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135143/discussion-on-answer-by-hold-to-the-rod-does-the-church-of-jesus-christ-of-latte).

Answer (score 1):

The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints believe [God](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/bd/god?lang=eng)

> created all things and is the ruler of the universe, being omnipotent, omniscient, and omnipresent (through His Spirit),...

this is because (from earlier in link)

> From latter-day revelation we learn that the Father and the Son have tangible bodies of flesh and bone and that the Holy Ghost is a personage of spirit without flesh and bone ([D&C 130:22–23](https://www.churchofjesuschrist.org/study/scriptures/dc-testament/dc/130.22-23?lang=eng#p22)).

Comment: Isaiah 31:3 distinguishes between flesh and spirit and the tenor of the passage echoes John 4:24 "God is a Spirit: and they that worship him must worship him in spirit and in truth.".  Job agrees also "Hast thou eyes of flesh? or seest thou as man seeth?".  The expected answer is no.

Comment: @MikeBorden the JST of John 4:24 reads: `26 For unto such hath God promised his Spirit. And they who worship him, must worship in spirit and in truth.`

Comment: New question:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/75295/what-is-the-manuscript-evidence-for-the-joseph-smith-translation-of-john-424

Comment: @MikeBorden I'm not an expert in hebrew or greek. If you asked on Christianity I could give an LDS answer but I don't have sufficient expertise to answer on that site

Comment: @MikeBorden or just read the [apologist response](https://www.fairlatterdaysaints.org/answers/Question:_How_is_John_4:24_used_as_a_proof-text_by_critics_of_Mormon_doctrine_of_the_corporeal_nature_of_God?) which has most of what I would answer

Comment: Thanks for the link but it didn't bring up any content :(

Comment: @MikeBorden the link is what I have in URL, must be some uri issue: [this page](https://www.fairlatterdaysaints.org/answers/Mormonism_and_the_nature_of_God) 3rd section click `Question: Does the Mormon doctrine that God has a physical body contradict the Bible's statement in John 4:24 that "God is a Spirit"?`